# iOS compare two object arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, nsarray, compare, mkmapview

I am trying to compare two object arrays to see if they contain the same data. One of the arrays is a map view's annotations and the other is a custom array of objects. It does not matter if they are in the same order or not, just I want to make sure that they contain the same objects. I would like to compare them based on one of the object's properties. It must also fail if one array has more or less than the other. Below is what I have accomplished so far.

In the example below, it should not fail as they contain the same objects. Thanks.

Code:

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:[[FCDataController sharedInstance] alarmData]];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:self.mapView.annotations];

if ([set1 isEqualToSet:set2]) {
    NSLog(@"both are same");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"both are differnt");
}

NSLog(@"Alarm = %@", set1);
NSLog(@"Map Data = %@", set2);
```

Result:

```
2014-11-19 16:03:04.662 FireCom[298:8787] both are differnt
2014-11-19 16:03:04.663 FireCom[298:8787] Alarm = {(
    <FCCall: 0x141aec0b0> Allergic C1 (45.501204, -122.916716),
    <FCCall: 0x141b4eb60> Breathing Prob. (45.401885, -122.284218),
    <FCCall: 0x141af6be0> Trauma (45.309056, -122.745360),
    <FCCall: 0x141b53030> Sick Person/unko (45.343586, -122.792549),
    <FCCall: 0x13de78a60> Chest Pain/heart (45.499593, -122.881558),
    <FCCall: 0x141b4fc00> Odor Investigate (45.290905, -122.331344),
    <FCCall: 0x141af68b0> Sick Person/unko (45.366520, -122.620110),
    <FCCall: 0x141af6d10> Invalid Assist (45.393609, -122.806652)
)}
2014-11-19 16:03:04.665 FireCom[298:8787] Map Data = {(
    <FCCall: 0x13de7b3f0> Sick Person/unko (45.366520, -122.620110),
    <FCCall: 0x13de63e80> Odor Investigate (45.290905, -122.331344),
    <FCCall: 0x13de7b780> Sick Person/unko (45.343586, -122.792549),
    <FCCall: 0x13de7b520> Trauma (45.309056, -122.745360),
    <FCCall: 0x13de63fb0> Chest Pain/heart (45.499593, -122.881558),
    <FCCall: 0x13de7b2c0> Allergic C1 (45.501204, -122.916716),
    <FCCall: 0x13de7b650> Invalid Assist (45.393609, -122.806652),
    <FCCall: 0x13de63d50> Breathing Prob. (45.401885, -122.284218)
)}
```

Edit:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToCall:(FCCall *)call
{
    // If we have no call
    if (!call) {

        // Then fail
        return NO;
    }

    // Return the check
    return (!self.incident && !call.incident) || [self.incident isEqualToString:call.incident];
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    // If they have the same memory addresses
    if (self == object) {

        // They are the same
        return YES;
    }

    // If they are not the same kind of class
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[FCCall class]]) {

        // They are not the same
        return NO;
    }

    // Return check
    return [self isEqualToCall:(FCCall *)object];
}

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    // Returh the hash
    return [self.incident hash];
}
```

Comment: Does your `FCCall` class implement proper `isEqual:` and `hash` methods?

Comment: No it does not. It is a subclass of NSObject. All it has it some custom properties so I can push data around in the app.

Comment: The default `isEqual:` is based on the object's pointer address. You need to implement your own to properly check if to `FCCall` objects represent the same data. Otherwise your check to see if the two sets are equal will never work.

Comment: @rmaddy So something like the first example in this article? http://nshipster.com/equality/

Comment: You want the section under "Implementing -isEqual: and hash in a Subclass".

Comment: @rmaddy Alright, I implemented it. How do I go about the comparison now? As I have it?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example with two dictionary, but properties in object works the same than key in dictionary in predicates.

I hope this is you look for:

```
// I have created two array the dict in order to test.
NSArray *alarmArray = @[@{@"name":@"Allergic",@"clock":@2},@{@"name":@"Person",@"clock":@2},@{@"name":@"Invalid Assist",@"clock":@2}];

NSArray *annotationsArraY = @[@{@"name":@"Allergic",@"lat":@2},@{@"name":@"Sick Person",@"lat":@2},@{@"name":@"Invalid Assist",@"lat":@2},@{@"name":@"OtroNom",@"lat":@2},@{@"name":@"last",@"lat":@2}];


// The filered Array:
NSArray *filteredArray;
if ([annotationsArraY count] > [alarmArray count])
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name in %@.name",alarmArray];
    filteredArray = [annotationsArraY filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
else
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name in %@.name",annotationsArraY];
    filteredArray = [alarmArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}



NSLog(@"Exit array is: %@",[filteredArray description]);

}
```

Comment: Of course you can add more properties to the predicate ( AND ...)

Comment: And in order to know if both are the same object, the filtered array count must be the same than the others.